# Does condition_variable::wait_for return true when cv is notified

Tags: c++

here is a small code snippet

```
request_ptr pop()
{
    request_ptr rp;

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(cv_mtx);
    auto time = std::chrono::milliseconds(10000);
    if (!cv.wait_for(lock, time, [this] { return !this->is_empty(); }))
    {
        return rp;
    }

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> mtx_guard(mtx);
    rp.reset(new request(std::move(requests.front())));
    requests.pop();
    return rp;
}
```

How does `wait_for` behave when `cv` is notified?
Does it return `true` without check of returned value of `is_empty`?
Or it returns `true` only if `is_empty` returns `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[thread.condition.condvar]/36](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition.condvar#36) the call...

```
cv.wait_for(lock, rel_time, pred);
```

is equivalent to...

```
cv.wait_until(lock, chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time, std::move(pred));
```

which is, [in turn](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition.condvar#30), equivalent to...

```
while (!pred())
    if (wait_until(lock, abs_time) == cv_status::timeout)
        return pred();
return true;
```

So the value returned by `wait_for` should be the current value as returned by the predicate.